# Setting Publishing target in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I'm trying add the remote server in my publishing targets. I have followed the procedure explained by the [Dheer rajpoot](http://www.bugdebugzone.com/2014/02/how-to-add-new-publishing-target-in.html).

After updating the web.config, when i tried to load Sitecore, its showing me following error

```
Unknown connection string. Name: 'SITtest'
```

[image]

In Sitecore I have created the publishing target as they have mentioned. I have verified name and it's correct.

[image]

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error say there is no Connection string with name SITtest.

Edit the /App_Config/ConnectionStrings.config and add a connectionstring with name SITtest to the Sitecore Web database associated with the target.

You have define the SITtest in the web.config `<sitecore><databases><database id="SITtest" ....>`

The id is used as name for a ConnectionString.

Comment: Unfortunately, It Should Be really simple to add a target. Check if you really edit the correct ConnectionString config file. In the web.config there is normally a line <connection strings config source = "App Config\ConnectionStrings.config" />